# PS Script: Match First 3 octets of IP address with IPArray

Tags: arrays, powershell, split, pattern-matching, match

Need help on PS Script.

**Requirement:** I would like to copy large files to multiple VM using FTP. I have FTP with multiple IP Ranges with Class C Subnet. 
Ex."10.10.10.10","10.11.10.10""10.10.12.10","10.10.10.13" (All are Class C with subnet 255.255.255.

The script will be executed locally on each VM. so I want the script to match first 3 octets of assigned IP(few VM have multiple IP's with different ranges too) and then pick the FTP IP from the list of IP address and set that as variable.

As per my knowledge, I created the IP array which contains all the FTP IP Address. Then I use **Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration** to get the list of IP address, Subnet, and Gateway. I put the **Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration** to the hash table so that I can use that for comparison.

Need help to compare hash table data and fetch the matched IP address from IP array and set that FTP IP as Variable.

**Ex**. If VM A have IP 10.10.12.25 then it should use 10.10.12.10 FTP IP.

I need to use **Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration** to make the script compatible with old operating systems running PS v2

```
$FTPIPs = @("10.10.10.10","10.11.10.10""10.10.12.10","10.10.10.13")
$AllIPs = @()
foreach ($adapter in (Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration -Filter IPEnabled=TRUE -ComputerName $env:COMPUTERNAME ))
        {
         $Prop = @{
                'IPAddress' = $adapter.IpAddress
                'SubnetMask' = $adapter.IPSubnet
                'DefaultGateway' = $adapter.DefaultIPGateway
         }      
$obj = New-Object -TypeName PSobject -Property $Prop
$AllIPs += $obj
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Created Script as below.

```
$FTPIPs = @("10.10.10.10","10.11.10.10","10.10.12.10","10.10.10.13")
$Prop = @{
    'IPAddress' = '10.11.10.54'
    'SubnetMask' = '255.255.255.128'
    'DefaultGateway' = '10.11.10.1'
}
$LocalIP = New-Object -TypeName PSobject -Property $Prop

$FTPIPs |
ForEach-Object {
    If ((([IPAddress]$LocalIP.IPAddress).Address -band ([IPAddress]$LocalIP.SubnetMask).Address) -eq (([IPAddress]$_).Address -band ([IPAddress]$LocalIP.SubnetMask).Address)) {
        "$_ is in the same subnet as $($LocalIP.IPAddress)"
    }
}
```